# Making dots disappear and reappear dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a couple of dots in my program, which are all under a collective matrix named

```
nodes[];
```

I need to make the last dot in the group, named

```
nodes[2];
```

to disappear when a certain event occurs. I've tried many different methods to make it disappear, such as

```
document.getElementById("nodes[2]").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and

```
nodes[2].style("opacity", "0");
```

but they don't seem to work. I would like to know of any methods that are used to make points temporarily invisible, please.

Here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/v92q26L8/

Comment: question: do you mean to set opacity to 0 and visibility to hidden? because setting it to visible and setting opacity to 1 means you can see it

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I used those ones to show the general framework that I used, but lemme change it to make it clearer.

Comment: that being side nodes[2] isn't exactly an ID on the page..... you may have meant to interpolate the nodes[2] and do nodes[2].id or something? its a bit harder without seeing the d3js code

Comment: Oh ok let me post the code first